# How to create an autosend email in vb.net?

Tags: .net

```
Dim mailmsg As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
    mailmsg.From = New MailAddress("yourname@domain.com")
    mailmsg.To.Add("to.domain.com")
    mailmsg.Subject = "Mail From .Net Application"
    mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = True
    mailmsg.Body = "Hi this is a mail from .net appl i have used same code......"
    mailmsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
    Dim client As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()

    client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourname@domain.com", "password")
    client.Port = "587"
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    client.EnableSsl = True
    Dim userstate As Object = mailmsg

    client.Send(mailmsg)
```

can you guys check my code if there's something wrong with my smtp? then i 
      want to add some codes for the attachment files can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is not for *plz give me teh codez* questions. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, especially [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=send+email+in+v.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5O7iWMGcBKWN8Qe8-biwDg#channel=fs&q=send+email+in+vb.net&*

Answer (score 0):

The mailmessage object has an attachments property which you can use like this:

```
mailmsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(PathToAttachment))
```

Are you sure you're using the correct port for Google's smtp? I thought it was port 465.

To test the mail functionality without worrying about the smtp issue you could try using a tool like smtp4dev, which gives you a local smtp server target. See it here: https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev

Comment: Try checking firewalls (windows firewall would be the first place to start). If my answer works please mark it as the accepted answer.